# Transferring a Domain Safely

Tags: domain-transfer, purchase

I want to transfer a domain that I am buying off somebody but I want to make sure i'm not getting scammed. Is there some kind of 3rd-party website that can help me with this kind of transfer so that I can safely buy the domain and move it over to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an escrow service like [escrow.com](https://www.escrow.com/solutions/domain_name/index.asp).

> **Ensuring Buyers get the Domain and Sellers get paid.**
>
> Whether you're
>   buying or selling domain names online, Escrow.com is a name you can
>   trust. Escrow.com is a government licensed and audited 3rd party that
>   safely holds a Buyer's payment in a trust account until the entire
>   transaction is complete. That way, Buyers can be confident the domain
>   will be registered in their name and Sellers can be sure they'll be
>   paid.
>
> **Escrow.com protects your money and your domain.**
>
> Since the Buyer pays
>   Escrow.com and not the Seller, Escrow.com can withhold payment until
>   it's satisfied the domain name has been transferred by the Seller. One
>   of the ways Escrow.com does this is by checking the WHOIS database of
>   the appropriate Registrar* to make certain it properly reflects the
>   new Buyer's name as the domain name Registrant. Once this has been
>   verified, Escrow.com releases payment to the Seller.
>
> **Buy and sell Domains without fear of fraud.**
>
> Anytime you pay in advance
>   for something you've purchased on the Internet, you're taking a
>   chance. People can forge their identities. They can misrepresent what
>   they're selling. And even with the best of intentions, some people are
>   just plain irresponsible.
>
> That's why it's important to turn to a trusted 3rd party like
>   Escrow.com for transactions involving a high risk of fraud like domain
>   name transfers. Relying on Escrow.com is like having an insurance
>   policy that protects you against fraud, deception and
>   irresponsibility.
>
> **Benefits for Buyers**
>
> - Peace of mind, Security, and Convenience
> - Assured Domain name transfer prior to paying Seller
> - Ability to confirm domain ownership directly with the registrar
>     before the seller is paid.
> - Ability to pay by wire transfer and in some cases PayPal, check,
>     money order, or credit card (Visa, MasterCard, American Express)
>     Restrictions apply
> - Ability to send credit card information to a financial institution,
>     not a stranger
> - Easy access to live customer support by phone or email
>
> **Benefits for Sellers**
>
> - Peace of mind, Security, and Convenience
> - Payment verification prior to Domain name transfer
> - Guaranteed payment once transfer specifications are met
> - Protection against credit card fraud, insufficient funds or credit
>     card chargebacks
> - Ability to accept credit cards and PayPal if otherwise not able to.
>     Restrictions apply
> - Escrow fees that may be lower than merchant credit card processing
>     fees
> - Easy access to live customer support by phone or email

Comment: "Since the Buyer pays Escrow.com and not the Seller, Escrow.com can withhold payment until it's satisfied the domain name has been transferred by the Seller." - - - - - How much does a service like this cost? Are there any free ones? I'm having trouble finding prices on this website. Being a small company being a high priced domain any kind of cost cuts would be better.

Comment: The fee varies depending on the amount of the deal. See [this calculator](https://www.escrow.com//support/calculator.asp) to determine your costs.